# Accessing NSDictionary retrieves an object instead of NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have an NSDictionary that I fill with JSON. It all looks great, and it is *partially* working for me. I am setting a property of my class that is of type NSString equal to a value for a certain key, which oddly enough sets my property equal to an object with the object being the string value I need.

The dictionary (printed description):

```
miscInfo:
<__NSArrayI 0x7494ab0>(
{
  Abbreviation = DR;
  DateInactive = "";
  Description = Drowsiness;
  ForQueue = 2430;
  IsAdditive = 0;
  IsReserved = 1;
  MiscCodeTypeStr = AVR;
  PluralDescription = "";
  ReservedDescription = Drowsiness;
}
```

I am setting it on my property like so:

```
self.ReactionName = [miscInfo valueForKeyPath:@"Description"];
```

Which produces:

[image]

I've tried casting it as NSString such as:

```
self.ReactionName = (NSString*)[allergenAdverseReaction valueForKeyPath:@"Description"];
```

but nothing gives. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you seeing some error or you're just confused by what you see in the debugger?

Comment: No there is no error at all. I'm also setting similar properties but instead of where mine says "@'1 object'" the others say their name I am after, in this case "Drowsiness"

Comment: Can you run `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([[miscInfo valueForKeyPath:@"Description"] class]));` and see what it says.

Comment: It's not wise to use valueForKeyPath when objectForKey will work just as well.  It's more likely to confuse than simplify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`miscInfo` is an *array* containing a dictionary, so

```
self.ReactionName = [[miscInfo objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Description"];
```

would give the result that you expect. Or, using the modern array and dictionary
subscripting syntax:

```
self.ReactionName = miscInfo[0][@"Description"];
```

---

**Remark:** In your code

```
self.ReactionName = [miscInfo valueForKeyPath:@"Description"];
```

`valueForKeyPath` is applied to each element of the array, and an *array* with all
the values is returned. That is what you see in the Xcode debugger window.

This "feature" can be very useful, but in general (as Hot Licks commented above)
`objectForKey` is the right method to get a value from a dictionary. And

```
self.ReactionName = [miscInfo objectForKey:@"Description"];
```

throws a descriptive runtime exception if `miscInfo` is not a dictionary as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like miscInfo is an array of dictionaries.  In that case valueForKey will return an array.  See if the code below works.  If it does, then it is an array of dictionaries.

```
self.ReactionName = [[allergenAdverseReaction valueForKeyPath:@"Description"]lastObject];
```

Comment: That did it. Man, I need you on payroll. You've bailed me out twice this week *high five*